# Representation of finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, unitary-representations

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite index subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Let $\pi$ be a natural covering from $\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H}$ to $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash\mathbb{H}$. Denote by $\text{Deck}(\pi)$ the group of deck transformations w.r.t $\pi$. My question is that are there theorems or methods to have a lower bound for the dimension of irreducible representations of $\text{Deck}(\pi)$ in term of index of $\Gamma$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$? Thank you.

Comment: (I don't see the relevance of the tag "unitary") If I don't miss anything $Deck(\pi)$ is the normalizer of $\Gamma$ modulo $\Gamma$, so the question is to have a lower bound for the dimensions of (nontrivial? some? all?) irreducibles of such a $N(\Gamma)/\Gamma$. This sounds a bit too broad... $N(\Gamma)/\Gamma$ can be trivial, or at the opposite $\Gamma$ can be normal and the quotient group $SL_2(\mathbf{Z})/\Gamma$ essentially arbitrary.

Comment: I mean all irreducible representations. For me $\Gamma$ is not normal.

Comment: $\Gamma$ is not normal is not a natural assumption and will not help. Take $\Gamma$ to be normal in a subgroup of index 2 essentially amounts to the same as the situation when $\Gamma$ is normal.